# What would cause bottle-carbonation to fail?

Tags: carbonation, mead, priming

I made a Hydromel (beer-strength mead) around 5% using champagne yeast. After fermentation I split it into a few small batches... some I added ginger, some I added orange zest, some remained un-modified.

After leaving for a while, I then primed it all and bottled. But for some reason while the un-modified version carbonated very nicely, the orange-zested one has remained totally flat. I don't know if the orange could be to blame, or if it's more likely the way I bottled it could have killed the yeast?

What are some common/likely reasons that bottle-carbonation wouldn't work, given that the sugar levels were the same?

Comment: It's a shame because the orange one is delicious!

Comment: Where did you get your orange zest from

Comment: An orange of course... will reply seriously to your answer

Comment: you can buy it ready for use. In a jar. Or big plastic containers. So not "of course".

Comment: I was only joking, but that is useful to know - never seen it before.

Comment: [here](http://www.amazon.com/The-Perfect-Puree-Napa-Valley/dp/B0002BBBX2) and [here](http://www.amazon.com/Frontier-Orange-Granules-Certified-Organic/dp/B001VNKVPE) are some examples. I'm not affiliated with them and never use these particular brands, just for reference.

Comment: Did the ginger batch carbonate?  That would tell you whether its something to do with the oranges.

Comment: @brewchez the plain batch carbonated. The ginnger carbonated a LOT.

Comment: Is it possible the ginger batch got the priming sugar that the orange should have gotten?

Comment: No - but the ginger actually caused carbonation when it was infusing _before_ I even did the priming. The sugar in it, or some wild yeast possibly. But all priming was done carefully. I think the chemicals are by far the most likely answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a common factoid that oranges are usually sprayed with fungicides for transport. If you do not wash them enough, some of it may end up in your mead and kill your yeast. My friend, who happens to be catering technician, always washes them for good few minutes using brush, if she wants to use zest for anything. Even longer before we put it in my beer.

Comment: I think that could be it... as far as I recall I just zested it without washing at all (figuring alcohol would kill germs). I think this seems likely, re-priming sounds like a pointless exercise so I'll have to make some more!

Comment: @Mr.BoyAt least dose you may have is low enough to be quite safe for humans.

Comment: Is washing the only solution? If for instance I made an "orange tea" would boiling water break down the chemicals?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Sorry, but warm water, brush and 5 to 15 minutes is the only way I know. These chemicals are designed to be quite persistent. And if they do break due to heat, how would you know resulting parts are not even more nasty?

Comment: Interesting idea, but I make an orange wheat in the summer with loads of orange peel in it and it ferments fine.  Not ruling it out though as I am pitching more yeast that's more healthy than at the end of a mead fermentation in this example.

Comment: @brewchez not all are sprayed the same way... You never know until you try.

Comment: You might get fresh oranges from CA/Florida... ours are shipped across the ocean :) I assume buying organic oranges would solve the problem?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Should. If they are honest about it, it should. I would still wash them, of course, because you can have wild yeast and other things on organic fruit.

Comment: Something about the fungicides/insecticides was just on a SYSK podcast. The recommended advice is, dilute some bleach in water, wash the fruit/veg in that, then rewash with clean water to wash the bleach off, that will kill off any fungicides/insecticides

Comment: @bizzehdee the problem with your comment is that fungicides are chemical compounds, not living things, and you can't kill what's not alive,  so there happened some error or misunderstanding at some point.

Comment: switch kill with either remove/sterilize/bleach/strip